# How to create flagged nodes views that show up to colorbox using custom link

Tags: 7, views

I Have flagged nodes, but because there are many flagged list with user, I want to show flagged list if user click on the text link as I describe on the picture. How to figure out this stuff?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Enable Colorbox load" option in Colorbox settings.

Create a page view that lists the flagged content with path of `/flagged/%`

Add Contextual filter of **Flags: User UID**

[image]

---

Now in your table view:

Add **User ID** field, and checkmark hide from display.

Add **Custom text** field to view

```
<a class="colorbox-load" href="/flagged/[uid]" width=300&height=150&top=40&right=20&iframe=true">Click here to show</a>.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I have tried this suggestion but every user found same flagged nodes, not their own flagged nodes. I need link produce flagged nodes by user on the [uid], not by all user or logged in user.

Comment: @masmalik see updated answer.